# Why can T not be deduced for std::span<T> when passing a std::vector?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction, std-span

In the following C++20 code, passing a `std::vector` to a templated function with a `std::span<T>` parameter fails, because obviously the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter. I have tried this with GCC, Clang and MSVC; all fail.

Invoking like this works: `f3(std::span(vi))` or `f3(std::span(vp))`.

I would like to know *why* this fails, because in my understanding, `std::vector` is a range, and `std::span` has a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/deduction_guides) for ranges.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <span>

void f1(std::span<int> s)
{
}

void f2(std::span<std::shared_ptr<int>> s)
{
}

template<typename T>
void f3(std::span<T> s)
{
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vp;

    f1(vi);
    f2(vp);
    f3(vi); // ERROR: no matching function for call to 'f3'
    f3(vp); // ERROR: no matching function for call to 'f3'

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a function argument participates in template argument deduction, no implicit conversions are allowed for that function argument.

Comment: Why does the std::span deduction guide for ranges have no effect? Shouldn't it allow such kind of conversions?

Comment: @FrankM I don't fully understand the rationale behind this rule, but no, it doesn't seem to have an exception for deduction guides.

Comment: @FrankM If you need a practical solution, perhaps just accept `T &&range`, then check with SFINAE if it's convertible to `std::span<??>`, and for which element type.

Comment: what if there is another `template <typename T> void f3(foo<T>)` and `foo` has also a deduction guide to be constructed from a vector? ... well ok then it could be an ambiguity error. Maybe just nobody proposed such exception yet.

Comment: @FrankM Class template argument deduction is not done on function parameters at all and the only cases where it is done use the syntax `std::span` without template argument list in the declaration (which therefore is not permitted for function parameters).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, why not constraints rather than SFINAE?

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't mean to exclude `requires`, and I consider `requires`-expression a form of SFINAE (unsure if a `requires`-clause counts as SFINAE).

Comment: Try `f3(std::span{vi});`

Comment: Or, skip template argument deduction: `f3<decltype(vi)::value_type>(vi);`

Comment: The specific wording for this is untrue (all function arguments always "participate" in template argument deduction, even if they have no effect. Even when they do, implicit conversions are allowed (e.g., a function argument can help deduce a pointer and then implicitly convert to a function pointer, a lvalue can help deduce template arguments for a base class then implicitly convert to the base class). Even "implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction" is untrue (see: https://godbolt.org/z/z8McajWfr )

Comment: @Artyer Hmm. What wording would you suggest?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is impossible. In the call ....

> ```cpp
> template<typename T>
> void f3(std::span<T> s) { /* ... */ }
> // [...]
>
> std::vector<int> vi;
> f3(vi);
> ```

... the `std::vector` `vi` is not a `std::span`, so the template parameter `T` cannot be deduced from it. Implicit conversions are not considered by function template argument deduction.

You have pointed out that there is a deduction guide, but that feature cannot be used here:

> Deduction guides are used when a *template-name* appears as a type specifier for a deduced class type.

- [[temp.deduct.guide]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#:deduction-guide)

This means that [the `std::span` deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/deduction_guides) ...

> ```cpp
> template< class R >
> span( R&& ) -> span<std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>>;
> ```

... could be used in a scenario like:

```cpp
f3(std::span(vi));
// or
std::span s = vi;
```

In either case, this forms a `std::span<int>`.

#### Solution

Overall, this is a well-known and quite annoying limitation of `std::span`. If you want a "generic span", the idiomatic solution is to accept a constrained range:

```cpp
#include <ranges>

template <std::ranges::contiguous_range R>
  requires /* TODO: additional constraints for the range value type? */
void foo(R&& r) {
    // ...
}
```

Since you're writing a function template anyway, making one which accepts any [`std::ranges::contiguous_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/contiguous_range) is just as good as writing one which only accepts `std::span`.

Most of the time, you could use a more relaxed range requirement though, such as [`std::ranges::forward_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/forward_range).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why this fails, because in my understanding,
> `std::vector` is a range, and `std::span` has a deduction guide for
> ranges.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021377/11638718) explains why this doesn't work. If you still want `f3(vi)` to work, you can do so by checking if the type `R` enables the deduction guide of the `std::span`:

```
#include <span>

template<class R>
  requires requires(R&& r) { std::span(std::forward<R>(r)); }
void use_as_span(R&& r) {
  std::span sp(std::forward<R>(r));
  // use span here
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xvY4e87aE)