# Instantiating a function template with a std::span<T> parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, std-span

I'm encountering an issue where the compiler seems unable to implicitly deduce the template argument `T` when I try to call `largest()` with a `std::vector<T>`. Explicitly specifying `T` (e.g., `largest<std::string>(myVector)`) works, but I'm seeking a deeper understanding of why this is necessary.

```cpp
std::string largest(std::span< std::string > elements);
template <typename T> std::optional<T> largest(std::span<T> elements);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::vector< std::string > elements { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    std::cout << largest(elements) << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> integers { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    // std::cout << largest(integers) << std::endl; COMPILER CAN'T RESOLVE OVERLOAD

    // correct version
    std::optional<int> maximum { largest<int>(integers) };
    if(maximum.has_value())
        std::cout << maximum.value() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string largest(std::span< std::string > elements) {

    std::string maximum {};
    for(const auto& element : elements) {

        if(auto ordering { element <=> maximum }; ordering == std::strong_ordering::greater)
            maximum = element;

    }

    return maximum;

}

template <typename T> std::optional<T> largest(std::span<T> elements) {

    if( elements.empty() ) return std::nullopt;
    T maximum {};

    for(const auto& element : elements) {

        if(auto ordering { element <=> maximum }; ordering == std::strong_ordering::greater)
            maximum = element;

    }

    return maximum;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, [Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) doesn't allow for conversions between types, it has to be an exact match. `std::vector` is not `std::span` and the [error message should say as much](https://onlinegdb.com/e8bKz8pJr) (eg: `template argument deduction/substitution failed: ‘std::vector’ is not derived from ‘std::span’`), but a `span` object can be constructed from a `vector` object at runtime.

Comment: What you might try instead is change the parameter to just `T` and not `span<T>`, and then create a `span` inside the function. Let the compiler deduce `T` to the full type of whatever container is being passed in. But I think that is going to conflict with your non-template overload, unless you use SFINAE to omit the template overload for containers holding `std::string` elements so the non-template is the only viable overload.

Comment: OT: `if(auto ordering { element <=> maximum }; ordering == std::strong_ordering::greater)` is terrible code. `ordering == std::strong_ordering::greater` should be `ordering > 0`, and then `(element <=> maximum) > 0` is just `element > maximum`.

Comment: @Artyer Is there a performance reason why that line of code is terrible or is it terrible from a readability perspective?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm For `std::string` it's readability, since `element > maximum` is rewritten to `(element <=> maximum) > 0`. For other types, there may be a performance difference and there may be a semantic difference (you may need to `static_assert(std::totally_ordered<T>)`

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022533/5754656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the compiler seems unable to implicitly deduce the template argument `T` when I try to call `largest()` with a `std::vector<T>`

Yes, for it to be possible to deduce `T`, you'd have to supply a `std::span` over "something". The match must be exact for deduction to work and a `vector<T>` and a `span<T>` are not the same type and it doesn't help that a `span<T>` has a converting constructor that lets it be created from a `vector<T>`.

You could however make it simpler by just accepting any forward range. To simplify it further, you could also use a standard algorithm to find the element with the maximum value.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>

auto largest(std::ranges::forward_range auto&& elements) {
    // get an iterator to the maximum element:
    auto maxit = std::ranges::max_element(elements);

    // create an empty optional with the correct value type:
    std::optional<std::iter_value_t<decltype(maxit)>> maximum;

    // if the range was not empty, assign the found value:
    if (maxit != std::ranges::end(elements)) maximum = *maxit;

    return maximum;
}
```